# Regex "\/~ece742[\w\d\/\.\?\=\-]+\.pdf" stops after matching "/~ece742/"

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to get the links for all the pdfs' in a file. It's my course website.

File name - doku.php\?id\=lectures

File Type - HTML

```
grep -Eo '\/~ece742[\w\d\/\.\?\=\-]+\.pdf' doku.php\?id\=lectures
```

This regex stops after finding "/~ece742/".

If I write

```
grep -Eo '\/~ece742\/\w+' doku.php\?id\=lectures
```

it does find some text after "/~ece742/" like "/~ece742/abc123".

Here is one of the blocks:

```
<td class="col1"> L6 <a href="/~ece742/f12/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=onur-18-742-fall12-lecture6-asymmetric-multicore-afterlecture.ppt" class="media mediafile mf_ppt" title="onur-18-742-fall12-lecture6-asymmetric-multicore-afterlecture.ppt">ppt</a> <a href="/~ece742/f12/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=onur-18-742-fall12-lecture6-asymmetric-multicore-afterlecture.pdf" class="media mediafile mf_pdf" title="onur-18-742-fall12-lecture6-asymmetric-multicore-afterlecture.pdf">pdf</a> <a href="http://youtu.be/hzUQc7NvAnc?list=PLSEZzvupP7hNjq3Tuv2hiE5VvR-WRYoW4" class="urlextern" title="http://youtu.be/hzUQc7NvAnc?list=PLSEZzvupP7hNjq3Tuv2hiE5VvR-WRYoW4"  rel="nofollow">YouTube Video</a> </td>
```

In this case I want to find-

"/~ece742/f12/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=onur-18-742-fall12-lecture6-asymmetric-multicore-afterlecture.pdf"

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Can you show some sample contents of the file?

Comment: BTW, you don't need to escape `/` with `grep`, and you don't need to escape `?`, `=`, and `.` inside square brackets.

Comment: And you don't need to escape `=` in filenames. It's usually easiest to just put filenames in quotes rather than escape each special character.

Comment: Added in the question

Comment: When I try it, it doesn't match anything. It works if I use `-Po` instead of `-Eo`.

Comment: Why do you need both `\w` and `\d` in the character class? `\w` matches letters, numbers, and underscore, `\d` matches numbers.

Comment: Wow! I was assuming grep would understand "\w", and with the -E flag. 

P.S: I realized i don't need \w and \d at the same time. And had edited it in my terminal, forgot to remove it while posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` doesn't recognize the escape sequences `\w` and `\d`. The equivalent in Extended Regexp is `[:alnum:]_`

```
grep -Eo '/~ece742[[:alnum:]_/.?=\-]+\.pdf' doku.php\?id\=lectures
```

If you want to use PCRE escape sequences, use `-P` instead of `-E`.